# How to copy python virtual environment flask project to another server and deploy the application in that server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, deep-learning

I am very new to python and flask.
I have created a python flask application for deep learning model with python virtual environment in my laptop. i need to copy this code to server and deploy there.
Would you please help me how to deploy this python code with virtual enviornment. This is my first time deploying the application, Any help would be appreciated.
Please find the attached screenshot of python code details.
Thank You all.[image]

Comment: You should recreate the venv on the new machine using your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**- create a requirements.txt file which will contain all the python packages list with the version. To create this file you can just run the below command to generate requirements.txt file on your local machine.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**Step 2**- Now, if you are using git then add this file in your git repository. make sure you have the whole project in the git repo except your virtual environment folder.

**Step 3**- Clone the git repository on your server.

```
git clone <repo url>
```

**Step 4**- Create a virtual environment in your project folder.

```
cd <yourproject>

virtualenv venv
```

**Step 5**- Activate virual environment

```
Source venv/bin/activate
```

**Step 6**- Install python packages by running the following command.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will install all the python packages which is required for this project to run

Answer (score 0):

There's two typos in the step 5 of Chetan Patel's answer, the code should be :

```
source env/bin/activate
```